# get the lines added to a file, and th lines deleted from a file in separate files

Tags: awk, sed

i have two different txt files. The first one is the source file. The second file file b is the same file, but after some edits. New lines have been added, and some lines from file A have been deleted .  Our task is to get in two new separate files the lines that have been added to file a, and in a new file the lines that have been removed from file a

`a.txt`

```
    Common
    Common
    A-ONLY
    Common
```

`b.txt`

```
    Common
    B-ONLY
    Common
    Common
```

I need as output in a separate new file to show lines removed from `a.txt`

output:

```
    A-ONLY
```

I then need as in a separate new file output to show lines added to `a.txt`

output:

```
    B-ONLY
```

How can i do it with ubuntu linux commands with sed or awk? do i first need to sort the files i compare?

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Regarding `do i first need to sort the files i compare` - no, but its a easier if you do. Can the files be sorted or is it better if they aren't?

Comment: i have tried with diff.. It would be better to sort the files before i do anything

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files can be sorted before comparison:

```
$ comm -23 <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt)
A-ONLY

$ comm -13 <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt)
B-ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU diff:

```
$ diff --unchanged-line-format= --new-line-format= a.txt b.txt
A-ONLY
```

```
$ diff --unchanged-line-format= --old-line-format= a.txt b.txt
B-ONLY
```

---

With standard diff and awk:

```
$ diff -u a.txt b.txt | awk 'NR>2 && sub(/^[-]/,"")'
A-ONLY
```

```
$ diff -u a.txt b.txt | awk 'NR>2 && sub(/^[+]/,"")'
B-ONLY
```

It is probably possible to implement with `awk` alone but you would just be trying to re-invent `diff`.

---

With standard diff and sed:

```
$ diff -u a.txt b.txt | sed -n '3,$s/^-//p'
A-ONLY
```

```
$ diff -u a.txt b.txt | sed -n '3,$s/^+//p'
B-ONLY
```

It's probably very difficult to implement with `sed` alone, if it is even possible.